nginx (or not) how to redirect a subdirectory
I used to have an old website at www.billoblog.com that mostly serves a small forensic pathology group.  I have moved it to wordpress.forensicpath.us.  I serve both of these on the same virtual server, and redirect from billoblog to forensicpath.
That works fine, and people who go to www.billoblog.com/wordpress are redirected to wordpress.forensicpath.us.
However, old links to a specific page do not redirect correctly.  The reason is that the at the old site, you had to point your browser directly to billoblog.com/wordpress, not just billoblog.com.   Old links, essentially have an extra "wordpress" stuck in there.
For instance,a page demonstrating a lesion (hepatocellular necrosis) is at:
https://wordpress.forensicpath.us/index.php/2020/10/24/pathology-cases-focal-hepatocellular-necrosis/
However, old links to "billoblog.com/wordpress/index.php/2020/10/24/pathology-cases-focal-hepatocellular-necrosis/
are being redirected to
https://wordpress.forensicpath.us/wordpress/index.php/2020/10/24/pathology-cases-focal-hepatocellular-necrosis/
This results in a 404 error because of that extra "wordpress" before index.php.
I cannot figure out how to redirect it.  I've tried:
Making a symlink in the wordpress directory to self, i.e. ln -s . wordpress.  That did nothing.
Making a directory "wordpress" in the wordpress directory and putting an htaccess file to redirect.  That didn't work because it came back with "forbidden", even with ownerships and such correct.
I've played with trying to get nginx to redirect, but I clearly have no clue as to what I'm doing.
I don't know what to do.
Here's my nginx file from sites-available for billoblog.com:

# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
#
# Default server configuration
#
server {

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/billoblog.com/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name billoblog.com www.billoblog.com;

        rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://wordpress.forensicpath.us/$1 permanent;


        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
                #added from linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-lemp-stack-ubuntu-24-04-server-desktop
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                #deny all;

        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
         allow all;
      }

        }



    access_log /var/log/nginx/billoblog.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/billoblog.com.error.log;



    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/billoblog.com-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/billoblog.com-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot



Here's the sites-available file for forensicpath.us:

# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##
# Default server configuration
#
server {

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/forensicpath.us/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name forensicpath.us www.forensicpath.us mail.forensicpath.us;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
                #added from linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-lemp-stack-ubuntu-24-04-server-desktop
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;


        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
         allow all;
      }

        }



    access_log /var/log/nginx/forensicpath.us.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/forensicpath.us.error.log;






    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.forensicpath.us/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.forensicpath.us/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot



}


server {
    if ($host = mail.forensicpath.us) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = www.forensicpath.us) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = forensicpath.us) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot



        server_name forensicpath.us www.forensicpath.us mail.forensicpath.us;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


Here's the conf.d file from wordpress.forensicpath.us:


#
server {
   server_name wordpress.forensicpath.us;
   root /var/www/forensicpath.us/html/wordpress;
   index index.php;
   disable_symlinks off;
   server_tokens off;
   client_max_body_size 64M;
location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
   location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass  unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
   }
   access_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress.forensicpath.us.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress.forensicpath.us.error.log;





    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/wordpress.forensicpath.us/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/wordpress.forensicpath.us/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = wordpress.forensicpath.us) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


   server_name wordpress.forensicpath.us;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}


Any help would be appreciated...

Try: rewrite ^/wordpress/(.*)$ http://wordpress.forensicpath.us/$1 permanent;

Amazing.  That worked perfectly.   Can you point me to a tutorial on this?  It seems like magic to me.  I have a little bit of a handle on regexp, but I'm having a hard time applying it here.  As an aside, I'm not sure how to mark a comment as an answer, so I'm not sure how to mark this as solved, but there you go.  Thanks.

You are redirecting from an old Wordpress site (https://old.example.com) to a new Wordpress site (https://wordpress.example.com).
You need to remove the path element wordpress from the beginning of the old URL.
For example:
https://old.example.com/wordpress/foo

Becomes:
https://wordpress.example.com/foo

The Nginx rewrite directive modifies a URL using a regular expression, and can issue a 301 response to permanently redirect the client's browser to the new URL.
The regular expression matches that part of the URL, after the host name but before the query string.
Use parentheses to capture that part of the URL following the word wordpress. The variable $1 represents everything captured between the first set of parentheses.
Try:
rewrite ^/wordpress/(.*)$ https://wordpress.example.com/$1 permanent;

In the example above, the regular expression tests the string /wordpress/foo. The ^ and $ are anchors which cause the entire string to be tested. The capture $1 is set to the value of foo. Notice that we have not captured a leading /.
The new URL is formed using $1 after a / (because we did not capture the leading /). In this example, rewrite will append the query string from the original request, then issue a permanent (301) redirect.
